Парсинг json js или node
Объясните пожалуйста что я не понимаю, задача из json файла:
{
  "containsTokens": false,
  "subtitles": [
    {
      "text": "bla-bla-bla",
      "startMs": 1129730,
    },
    {
      "text": "bla-bla-bla",
      "startMs": 1130920,
    },
  ]
}

достать содержимое поля

"text":

нужно объеденить все значения в один файл - "bla-bla-bla" + "bla-bla-bla" ....
пишу код на node js
import fs from 'fs';
import grab from './data.json';

let combinedText = '';

for (const subtitle of grab.subtitles) {
  combinedText += subtitle.text + '\n';
}

fs.writeFileSync('combined_text.txt', combinedText);


пробовал не получается, как прочитать json c помощью js или nodejs ?

fs.readFileSync и JSON.parse

И в тексте вопроса нет ничего про перенос строки

И что собственно не работает?

Заработало, всем спасибо
import fs from 'fs';

const rawData = fs.readFileSync('./data.json', 'utf8');
const data = JSON.parse(rawData);

let combinedText = '';

for (const subtitle of data.subtitles) {
  combinedText += subtitle.text + '\n';
}

fs.writeFileSync('combined_text.txt', combinedText);

